# Is ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 a part of ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms, .net-4.0

Is ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 a part of ASP.NET 4.0? E.g., by using ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0 do I automatically have ASP.NET AJAX 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it. Starting with ASP.NET 3.5, ASP.NET AJAX is part of ASP.NET.

<strike>You only need the appropiate Web.config sections so script handlers and related types will be loaded and ASP.NET AJAX will be available for you!</strike>

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET 4.0's web.config have all the ASP.NET AJAX bits predefined by default?